# Add Custom link in customer account navigation in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, customer, customer-account, forms, link

How to add custom link in **customer account navigation**?

I am looking for code to show form upon clicking custom link on left navigation.

Can we submit form using custom link?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want to do **sort** the link to then follow. Create **default.xml**  in following directory

**app/code/SpaceName/ModuleName/view/frontend/layout**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © 2016 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>   

    <referenceBlock name="customer_account_navigation">
                <block class="Magento\Customer\Block\Account\SortLinkInterface" name="test-link">
                    <arguments>
                        <argument name="path" xsi:type="string">test/controller/action</argument>
                        <argument name="label" xsi:type="string">Test Link</argument>
                         <argument name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">150</argument>
                    </arguments>
                </block>
    </referenceBlock>

  </body>
</page>
```

[Reference](https://blog.qaisarsatti.com/magento_2/magento-2-add-custom-link-customer-navigation/)

Comment: Hello Qaisar, How to load content upon clicking link, i can see Test link now in Account navigation. I am trying to load js data tables data from db on clicking it. How that can be done pls?

Comment: @jafar you have to add your module code in question so i can help further.

Comment: @Quisar , Which code is need to add ? I used the above code in my default.xml file and i can see link on account navigation now. How can i bring html on right side after clicking the link?

Comment: @jafar follow this link to create page. https://blog.qaisarsatti.com/magento_2/magento-2-create-helloworld-module/  in layout file just use this handle `<update handle="customer_account"/>`

Comment: hello Qaisar, where can i use this code <update handle="customer_account"/>?
I created the layout file in my module it is loading html content, but it is not on right hand side. how to bring it?

Comment: @jafar share your code..

Answer (score 4):

Create a layout file `customer_account.xml` inside `Vendor\Module\view\frontend\layout` and put below code.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="sidebar.main">
                <referenceBlock name="customer_account_navigation">
                    <block class="Vendor\Module\Block\Customer\Link" name="new-customer-link">
                        <arguments>
                            <argument name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">new Customer Link</argument>
                            <argument name="path" xsi:type="string">frontname/controller/action</argument>
                            <argument name="custom_form_action" xsi:type="string">kanhaiya5590.com</argument>
                            <argument name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">110</argument>
                        </arguments>
                    </block>
                </referenceBlock>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

As per **`question need form to be trigger on click of link or button`**

```
namespace Vendor\Module\Block\Customer;

use Magento\Customer\Model\Session as CustomerSession;
use Magento\Framework\App\DefaultPathInterface;
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Link\Current;
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context;

class Link extends Current
{   
    protected $_customerSession;


    public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        DefaultPathInterface $defaultPath,
        CustomerSession $customerSession,
        array $data = []
    )
    {
        $this->_customerSession = $customerSession;       
        parent::__construct($context, $defaultPath, $data);
    }

    protected function _toHtml()
    {
        $html = null;
        if ($this->_customerSession->isLoggedIn()) {
            $html = '<li class="nav item '.($this->isCurrent().?"current": "").'">';
                $html .= '<form action="'.$this->getCustomFormAction().'">'; 
                $html .= '<button>'.$this->escapeHtml((string)new \Magento\Framework\Phrase($this->getLabel())).'</button>';
                $html .= '</form>'; 
            $html .= '</li>';
        }
        return $html;
    }

}
```

Note :  custom_form_action as per your need you can set

if still more help needed please let us know.

Comment: I am looking for code to add link on leftnav, After clicking a link a form should open in right side. from there  i am trying to submit.

Comment: ok best to set a modal popup on click and then set you form data in popup

Comment: Yes, my total requirement is upon clicking link on leftnav, i need to load data table on right side with edit and delete each row, how can load the data after clicking link. please suggest me

Comment: as per your reply you want to load data or form  in right side area then best approch to use controller only, if your requirement is to show your data in any page of customer account secion then try to implement modal popup

Comment: @jafar, you might got my point further help need let us know.

Comment: if you satisfied with my share answer or with approach please mark the answer is valid answer.so it will help other those who looking same logic

Comment: I think you are getting my requirement, upon clicking custom link on left nav how can i show grid on right side with all rows?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/81038/discussion-between-jafar-and-kanhaiya-lal).